# ImageMagick Convert single frame = file not found

Tags: video, zsh, php

I am trying to extract the fist frame of a video

`convert ./video.mp4[0] ./sample.jpg`

I get file not found if I put `[0]`

it works without `[0]` but this is not what I want

All examples on the net suggest to use `[0]`

I am guessing this is a mac specific issue ?

```
ed@wakeio files samples % convert ./video.mp4[0] ./sample.jpg
zsh: no matches found: ./video.mp4[0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[0]` has a special meaning for shells like `bash` and `zsh`. Try

```
convert './video.mp4[0]' ./sample.jpg
```

Comment: worked like a charm :)

Comment: would that work in bash too ?

Comment: @applebee it's the same for all